AWS codebuild fails to build docker file. Environment is externally managed : ERROR
Few months ago AWS Codebuild used to build docker file successfully. Now after new changes I pushed the build and tried to build and it doesn't work. The build logs shows the following error:
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u7) ...
Removing intermediate container 59eb038789d6
 ---> 4d864f03be13
Step 6/27 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 7921c1b93c88
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is the Docker file content which used to build before but not now:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-dev build-essential



RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools && pip3 install awscli

COPY Backend/Deploy/entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Backend/Api/Api.csproj Backend/Api/
COPY Shared/Api.DTO/Api.DTO.csproj Shared/Api.DTO/
COPY Backend/Backend.Core/Backend.Core.csproj Backend/Backend.Core/
COPY Backend/Database.Core/Database.Core.csproj Backend/Database.Core/
COPY Backend/Database.Enums/Database.Enums.csproj Backend/Database.Enums/
COPY Shared/Backend.SharedLogic/Backend.SharedLogic.csproj Shared/Backend.SharedLogic/
RUN dotnet restore "Backend/Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Backend/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh", "dotnet", "Api.dll"]


This is just a docker build error, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with AWS other than you happen to be running the docker build on an AWS service. Do you not get the same error when you build this locally?

RUN apt-get install python3.11-venv -y
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv

# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN /opt/venv/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN /opt/venv/bin/pip3 install --upgrade setuptools && /opt/venv/bin/pip3 install awscli

I was able to resolve the issue by creating python virtual environment and installing python packages in it.

Another way to resolve this issue is to revert back .NET version from .NET 8 to .NET 6 and Docker file will built successfully
